# Azure Cosmos DB Entity Insert and Data Explorer Error

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

Just this morning when trying to view the Data Explorer UI for an Azure Cosmos DB table the window is totally blank and I see no rows (the table should not be empty). The only connection to this table is a Python script that pushes in simple rows with only a few variables however this has also stopped working just this morning.

I am still able to connect to the table service properly and I've even been able to create a new table through my Python script. However, as soon as I call `table_service.insert_or_replace_entity('traps', task)` ('traps' is the name of my table and task is the row I'm trying to push up) I receive back an `HTTP Error 400. The request URL is invalid.`

For reference, my connection in Python is as follows where Account_Name = my personal account name and Account_Key = my personal account key.

```
table_service = TableService(connection_string="DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=Account_Name;AccountKey=Account_Key;TableEndpoint=https://Account_Name.table.cosmosdb.azure.com:443/;")

for i in list(range(0,len(times))):
        print(len(tags))
        print(len(times))
        print(len(locations))
        task = {'PartitionKey': '1', 'RowKey': '{}'.format(tags[i]),'Date_Time' : '{}'.format(times[i]), 'Location' : '{}'.format(locations[i])}
        table_service.insert_or_replace_entity('traps', task)
```

**UPDATE**

In reference to the `HTTP Error 400` I discovered that I was trying to push a `\n` at the end of each of the `tags` string (i.e. `tags[0] = 'ab123\n'`). Stripping out the `\n` has resolved the HTTP 400 error but I am now receiving `The specified resource does not exist.` message when I attempt to upload which makes more sense as at why my Data Explorer is blank. I have tried uploading to a new table but its the same thing.

**Second Update**

Silly mistake on resource not found error was that my table is called "Traps" not "traps". Data appears to be uploading correctly now on the API side. However, the table is still not displaying at all in the data explorer page of the Azure portal. If anyone has insight on this it would be appreciated because the explorer is super helpful while we are still in development.

**Third Update**

I am able to connect to the table/database through Python and query data effectively. It all seems to be in there and up to date. The only thing I'm left unsure about is why the Data Explorer is not displaying properly. Aside from that, my recommendation is to obviously check your capital letters (my usual mistake haha) and DO NOT try to push up line feeds (`\n`) in the task/payload.

Comment: I can confirm that the Cosmos DB Data Explorer for Table API is not displaying data correctly/at all. I am looking into this,

Comment: Also, can you confirm which Python package you installed for your project? Something like: azure-storage-table

Comment: Hi thanks for your response. To answer your question, I installed the entire azure package i.e. `pip install azure`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Want to provide an official update and response to your issue. This issue is being Hotfixed with an ETA rolled out by Monday (09/24/2018).